# How do I delete newly allocated char that is also the function return value?

Tags: c++, string, stream, char

What will happen with `array1` after I return it? Will it delete itself or will the space be inaccessible? How do I `delete[]` it?

```
char* ToCharArray() {

    stringstream COUT;
    COUT << *day<< "." << *month<< "." << *year<< " " << *hours<< *minutes;
    string temp = COUT.str();
    int vel = strlen(temp.size) + 1;
    char *array1= new char[vel];
    strcpy_s(array1, vel, temp.c_str());

    return array1;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons you should be using the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class.

Comment: _"How do I delete[] it?"_ You call `delete[] ToCharArray();`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am well versed with string its just this is a a example in my college text book, you need to return char* with new used.If it was string I would know how to do it easily

Comment: @user0042 can you please elaborate?

Comment: @King23 As shown in the answer you call `delete []` on the pointer returned.

Comment: A useful technique to use when you're using APIs you can't change to return container types or smart pointers: capture the return value into a smart pointer.  e.g. `std::unique_ptr<char[]> res { ToCharArray() };`  Then from there the smart pointer will take care of managing the lifetime of the array for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delete it as you usually delete arrays in *C++*: with `delete[]`:

```
const char* p = ToCharArray();
// ...
delete[] p;
```

However, note, that the second part of `ToCharArray()` is pointless. You might return `std::string` and avoid possible memory leaks:

```
std::string ToCharArray() {
    stringstream COUT;
    COUT << *day<< "." << *month<< "." << *year<< " " << *hours<< *minutes;
    return COUT.str();
}
```

Comment: It is example code in my college,not mine, and the point is to return the char array with "new". If it asked for string I wouldn't have needed to post it here

Comment: @King23 Ok, I see, just remember, that if you allocate a memory with `new/new[]`, you have to free it with the corresponding form of `delete/delete[]`, but using containers is a *preferable* way to do the things...

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Containers are preferable in real code, but they don’t always fulfill your needs, so it’s good to know how to handle things manually. It’s easier to learn that with simple examples than with a complex example where none of the standard containers work.

Comment: @Edgar Rokyan does you first code also work if the function is part of a class?

Comment: @King23 If it's part of a class the pointer is probably managed by that class internally. Then the right place to call `delete[]` would be the destructor. The principle stays the same though.

Comment: @King23 the main principle is: if you allocate a memory, you have to release it. And this principle doesn't depend on a place where the memory was exactly allocated.

Comment: @DanielH yep, I would agree with you. But containers are... awesome :)

Comment: Yep, and even if you can’t use them a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` is better than a raw `char*`.

Comment: @DanielH exactly!

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++, it's best to avoid raw `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` as much as possible in favor of using standard container classes and smart pointers, and if you do have a need for manual memory management then you should try to encapsulate that as much as possible into a container class.  And with C++17, you usually shouldn't even need raw pointers - if you have a pointer that you don't own, you can annotate that fact by using `std::observer_ptr<T>`.  In particular, smart pointer types can be used to annotate lifetime expectations; for example, if a function returns a pointer to something it expects the caller to delete when it's done with it, it should return a `std::unique_ptr<T>`.  Similarly, if a function expects to take unique ownership of an object being passed in by pointer and be able to free the memory when it's done, then it should take that argument as a `std::unique_ptr<T>`.  The given function violates this design principle.

However, there will certainly be times when you'll want to use a third-party library which doesn't follow these design principles, and which you don't want to (or can't) edit the source code to.  In those cases, what I like to do is to create smart pointers as soon as possible after getting return values from such API functions; this way, I get the maximum benefit out of following the modern C++ idioms outlined above for my code.  In this case, that would look like:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> res { ToCharArray() };
```

Then when this object goes out of scope, the compiler will generate the code to free the memory for you.  (Even if something between this line and the end of the containing block ends up throwing an exception which is not caught in that block.)

Similarly, in the case of a function expecting to take ownership of a pointer, I keep it in the `unique_ptr<T>` as long as possible, then pass `p.release()` as that argument of the function.

If this is a function which you tend to use often, it might help to create a modern C++ wrapper around the legacy C++ API:

```
inline std::unique_ptr<char[]> wrap_ToCharArray() {
    return std::unique_ptr<char[]> { ToCharArray() };
}
```

This has benefits such as better exception safety for an expression like `f(wrap_ToCharArray(), wrap_ToCharArray())`.  (Look up the rationale for `std::make_unique` if you are interested in the details of why this has better exception safety than `f(std::unique_ptr<char[]> { ToCharArray() }, std::unique_ptr<char[]> { ToCharArray() })`.)